# What is the fastest way to check if a string contains repeating characters in Python 3?

Tags: string, list, python-3.x, filter, set

I need to filter strings by the criterion that they **contain no character twice**.

- The strings are **many** (say 1.4 trillion).
- The strings are **short** (around 8 characters).
- The strings are **unique** (caching won't work).
- The strings have a **big character set** (say any Unicode character).
- The strings **usually meet the criterion** (say 2/3 have no repeating characters).

The using code would look like this:

```
>>> candidate_strings = ["foobnehg", "barfnehg", "bazfnehg"]
>>> result_strings = [s if unique_chars(s) for s in candidate_strings]
>>> print(result_strings)
["barfnehg", "bazfnehg"]
```

I implemented a naive version, simply iterating the string:

```
def unique_chars_naive(string_given):
    """
    Checks if a given string contains only unique characters.
    This version iterates the given string, saving all occurred characters.
    """
    chars_seen = []
    for char in string_given:
        if char in chars_seen:
            return False
        chars_seen.append(char)
    return True
```

My next-best idea was to use a `set`, so I implemented that:

```
def unique_chars_set(string_given):
    """
    Checks if a given string contains only unique characters.
    This version exploits that a set contains only unique entries.
    """
    return len(string_given) == len(set(string_given))
```

Saving the functions to a file `UniqueCharacters.py`, timed them:

```
$ python3 -m timeit -n 100000 --setup='import UniqueCharacters; candidate_strings = ["foobnehg", "barfnehg", "bazfnehg"]' '[UniqueCharacters.unique_chars_naive(s) for s in candidate_strings]'
100000 loops, best of 3: 20.3 usec per loop

$ python3 -m timeit -n 100000 --setup='import UniqueCharacters; candidate_strings = ["foobnehg", "barfnehg", "bazfnehg"]' '[UniqueCharacters.unique_chars_set(s) for s in candidate_strings]'
100000 loops, best of 3: 17.7 usec per loop
```

This shows that the `unique_chars_set` is faster by about 15 % for this dataset.

Is there a faster way to do this? With regular expressions maybe? Is there some method in the standard library that does this?

Comment: Might there be repeated strings in `candidate_strings`?

Comment: Test with longer words.

Comment: Do all the strings contain only lowercase alphabetical characters? If not, do they only contain ASCII characters?

Comment: Maybe use a array with 26 elements - you can map each char to an element in this array very quickly as chars are just ints. You can then set a flag in the cell if the letter is present and if it's already set you have a duplicate. This would be a variant of a bucket sort.

Comment: I doubt any solution will be faster than the one using set, even for longer words.

Comment: @PedroWerneck I would imagine that my solution would be faster - it's basically a HashSet optimised for the problem at hand.

Comment: Did you look into using a [counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)?   Something like (Counter('abracadabra').most_common(1)[0][1] > 1) might be pretty fast.

Comment: @bmorris591 your solution is basically the same thing a set() does, and you'll have to implement it in python code. I doubt any naive implementation of that can be faster than the builtin set.

Comment: @Jared, @steven-rumbalski The `candidate_strings` are typically short. Think passwords.

Comment: @Kevin The strings do not contain only alphabetical characters. Any character is allowed. Think German "Umlaut"s, French Accents etc.

Comment: 13.4 *microseconds* per loop is about 74,000 per second.  Just how large is your dataset that this is unacceptable performance?

Comment: @steven-rumbalski All passwords from printable ASCII and a length of 8 would take 219 days to filter at that speed. I can apply faster filters beforehand, but there might still be a reasonable amount left.

Comment: If even the set solutions isn't fast enough for your practical needs, you should consider using pypy, psyco, or even another language, like go.

Comment: @PedroWerneck Alternative Implementations might be an option, but let's say, I need to stick with cPython for this question.

Comment: @bngtlrs:  You really have 1.4 trillion passwords?  Or are you generating them?  If you are generating them just use `itertools.combinations(legal_characters, 8)` and you will get no repeated characters.

Comment: This is also a trivially-parallelizable task. Consider using a `multiprocessing.Pool` and a worker per core with your `len(s)==len(set(s))` method.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I create the string myself and could use `itertools.combinations`, one might need to filter strings created by another component, so let's ignore that possibility.

Comment: @FrancisAvila Parallelization is viable for me. Still one will want to use the fastest algorithm for the workers. So let's ignore parallelization for this question.

Comment: @bngtlrs:  How common is it to find duplicate characters in your string?  If it's very likely you'll want to chose a method that short circuits execution on the first duplicate. Also, since these are passwords I suggest doing your timings with eight character strings. The performance characteristics may very well be different for a length of eight.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Duplicate characters are sparse. See also the last edits to my answer in which I specified these properties and expanded my example to use 8 character long strings.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let me start off by saying that I suspect that you are optimizing when you don't need to. Python is a high-level language that supports thinking about computation in a high-level manner. A solution that is readable, elegant, and reusable is often going to be better than one that is blazingly fast, but hard to understand.

When, and **only** when, you determine that speed is an issue, then you should proceed with the optimizations. Perhaps even write a C extension for the computationally intense parts.

That being said, here's a comparison of a few techniques:

```
def unique_chars_set(s):
    return len(s) == len(set(s))

def unique_chars_frozenset(s):
    return len(s) == len(frozenset(s))

def unique_chars_counter(s):
    return Counter(s).most_common(1)[0][1] > 1

def unique_chars_sort(s):
    ss = ''.join(sorted(s))
    prev = ''
    for c in ss:
        if c == prev:
            return False
        prev = c
    return True

def unique_chars_bucket(s):
    buckets = 255 * [False]
    for c in s:
        o = ord(c)
        if buckets[o]:
            return False
        buckets[o] = True
    return True
```

And here is the performance comparisons (in IPython):

```
In [0]: %timeit -r10 [unique_chars_set(s) for s in candidate_strings]
100000 loops, best of 10: 6.63 us per loop

In [1]: %timeit -r10 [unique_chars_frozenset(s) for s in candidate_strings]
100000 loops, best of 10: 6.81 us per loop

In [2]: %timeit -r10 [unique_chars_counter(s) for s in candidate_strings]
10000 loops, best of 10: 83.1 us per loop

In [3]: %timeit -r10 [unique_chars_sort(s) for s in candidate_strings]
100000 loops, best of 10: 13.1 us per loop

In [4]: %timeit -r10 [unique_chars_bucket(s) for s in candidate_strings]
100000 loops, best of 10: 15 us per loop
```

Conclusion: `set` is elegant and faster than many other obvious methods. But the differences are so small, it doesn't matter anyway.

For more benchmarks, see [@FrancisAvila](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15751669/716118)'s answer.

Answer (score 4):

I created a file with a timing and testing harness to try a whole bunch of different approaches.

The fastest one I found is regex-based, but it's only a tiny bit faster than your fastest `len(set())`-based approach. It's the `isunique_reg()` function below.

```
import re
import array
import collections
import bisect

re_dup_g = re.compile(r'(.).*\1', re.DOTALL)
re_dup_ng = re.compile(r'(.).*?\1', re.DOTALL)


def isunique_reg(s, search=re_dup_g.search):
    return search(s) is None

def isunique_reng(s, search=re_dup_ng.search):
    return search(s) is None

def isunique_set(s, set=set, len=len):
    return len(s) == len(set(s))

def isunique_forset(s, set=set):
    seen = set()
    add = seen.add
    for c in s:
        if c in seen:
            return False
        add(c)
    return True

def isunique_array(s, array=array.array):
    seen = array('u')
    append = seen.append
    for c in s:
        if c in seen:
            return False
        append(c)
    return True

def isunique_deque(s, deque=collections.deque):
    seen = deque()
    append = seen.append
    for c in s:
        if c in seen:
            return False
        append(c)
    return True

def isunique_bisect(s, find=bisect.bisect_right, array=array.array):
    seen = array('u')
    insert = seen.insert
    for c in s:
        i = find(seen, c)
        if i and seen[i-1] == c:
            return False
        insert(i, c)
    return True

def isunique_bisectl(s, find=bisect.bisect_right):
    seen = []
    insert = seen.insert
    for c in s:
        i = find(seen, c)
        if i and seen[i-1] == c:
            return False
        insert(i, c)
    return True

def isunique_count(s, Counter=collections.Counter):
    return Counter(s).most_common(1)[0][1]==1

def isunique_list(s):
    seen = []
    append = seen.append
    for c in s:
        if c in seen:
            return False
        append(c)
    return True


def _test():
    funcs = [f for n,f in globals().items() if n.startswith('isunique_')]
    cases = [
        (u'string given', False),
        (u'string uoqzd', True),
    ]
    for func in funcs:
        for s,rv in cases:
            try:
                assert rv is func(s)
            except AssertionError, e:
                print "%s(%r) is not %r" % (func.__name__, s, rv)
                raise e

def _time():
    import timeit
    funcs = [f for n,f in globals().items() if n.startswith('isunique_')]
    funcs.sort(key=lambda f: f.__name__)
    cases = [
        ('!uniq', u'string given', False),
        ('uniq', u'string uoqzd', True),
    ]

    casenames = [name for name, _, _ in cases]
    fwidth = max(len(f.__name__) for f in funcs)
    timeitsetup = 's = {!r}; from __main__ import {} as u'

    print('{: <{fwidth}s}|{: >15s}|{: >15s}'.format('func', *casenames, fwidth=fwidth))
    print('-'*(fwidth+2+15+15))
    for f in funcs:
        times = [timeit.timeit('u(s)', setup=timeitsetup.format(input, f.__name__)) for _, input, _ in cases]
        print('{: <{fwidth}s}|{: >15.10f}|{: >15.10f}'.format(f.__name__, *times, fwidth=fwidth))

if __name__=='__main__':
    _test()
    _time()
```

On CPython 2.7.1 I get the following results (unfortunately I don't have a CPython 3.x handy):

```
func            |          !uniq|           uniq
------------------------------------------------
isunique_array  |   6.0237820148|  11.0871050358
isunique_bisect |  10.8665719032|  18.4178640842
isunique_bisectl|   8.2648131847|  13.9763219357
isunique_count  |  23.1477651596|  23.5043439865
isunique_deque  |   4.0739829540|   7.3630020618
isunique_forset |   2.8148539066|   4.1761989594
isunique_list   |   3.6703650951|   6.9271368980
isunique_reg    |   1.7293550968|   2.8794138432
isunique_reng   |   1.9672849178|   3.3768401146
isunique_set    |   2.3157420158|   2.2436211109
```

You'll notice that when a string is not unique, the regex-based approach is faster than the set-based one, but the worst-case for the regex-based approach is slower than for sets.

Comment: I tried using a set, as you suggested. For the 3 strings in my example it is 40 % slower than using a list. The insert time seems to overweight the time for the membership test at short lengths. I added seldomly repeating characters as a requirement.

Comment: @bngtlrs, I completely rewrote my answer with a survey of approaches, and discovered a regex approach that is a (tiny bit) faster than `len(set(s))`.

Comment: The RegEx you used [was suggested and rejected](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15751247/906658) for being slower here before. I extended your answer with results for Python 3 that confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if will be faster, but this regular expression might satisfy you:

```
couplet = re.compile(r'(.).*\1')
result_strings = [s if not re.search(couplet, s) for s in candidate_strings]
```

Comment: Nice try, but actually slower.

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the string and iterate it to see if there are no consecutive same letters, but this is N*log(N) so I'm not sure this will be faster than the set solution.

Comment: Iterating over string is an O(N) solution, so it won't be faster for large strings.

Comment: But at each character you'd still have to compare against all the previous characters in some way. I'm certainly not convinced it's `O(N)` like you say. The sorting's certainly interesting, though similar in approach to the `set`. It has the nice benefit of early termination, though.

Comment: See `unique_chars_sort(s)` in [voithus' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15751659/906658) for a solution that sorts and looks for consecutive same letters. This is two times slower than the fastest solution.

Answer (score 0):

See [bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) although it a sorting algorithm you can base your solution in that, basically you define an array of n positions and for each char you place it in the array on  position given by its ASCII or UNICODE value (see below for unicode), you will have O(n) time complexity in each iteration at most (you can break when a position in the array is already used) ... but I think you won't find a considerable difference in either method given that you can simply check at first `if(string.length < 255)` or whatever is the number of possible valid values in the string.

That check ensures that any loop will be at most over 255 characters, which make them small small enough to have worries about performance in most cases

(I don't know python, but I'm sure there is some `string.length` property or equivalent)

As mentioned by @JOHN, if you need to support a large or all possible string values then this will cause problems with both space and time

Comment: absolutely, if support for all possible unicode characters is required then different considerations should be taken. It is not a common scenario to have to support ALL possible unicode characters

Comment: Well, you can't support only *some* unicode chars. It's all or nothing. :)

Comment: @J0HN: Welp, technically the code points for ASCII are also valid UTF-8 code points. So, I could argue that by supporting ASCII I am supporting a "limited subset" of Unicode. :o)

Comment: @voithos ага, конечно :) This were some symbols from a subset of unicode. Lucky for you, SO uses UTF to process it, so you see it just as I do. However, if it support only "limited subset" of unicode (as you labeled ASCII) you'll get a bunch of non-readable characters that happen to be at the same code points in your machine locale. So, you won't get consistent results. I wouldn't call it "supporting" :)